# non-static resources in Spring

Tags: java, spring, resources, mapping

I got Spring 2.5.6 and I'm trying to implement some stupid functionality within.

I have a photo directory somewhere in my server machine and **I want to expose these photos to the user**. What is the common solution for this issue?

P.S.
By now I'm writing my photos to the response using my own controller, and that is not very handy for me, cause I want to keep my photo's url nice and friendly (for example like `/myServlet/images/012345.jpg`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having your own controller is a fine solution. Here is a simplified copy from my `PictureController`:

```
@RequestMapping("/pictures/{filename}.{extension}")
public void getPicture(@PathVariable String filename,
        @PathVariable String extension, OutputStream outputStream,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    DateTime cachePeriod = new DateTime();
    cachePeriod = cachePeriod.plusDays(5);
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", cachePeriod.getMillis());
    pictureService.writePicture(filename + "." + extension, outputStream);
}
```

Where `pictureService` simply does `IOUtils.copy(imageStream, outputStream)`

Comment: Looks very simple and clear. Can I implement similar mapping within xml?

Comment: you mean, similar to `@RequestMapping`? I don't know, the last xml request-mapping that I wrote was a long time ago. Why don't you use the annotation approach (since spring 2.5)

Comment: I also prefer annotation approach, but this is... sort of requirement.

Comment: that's odd.. I hate when people make wrong decisions and tell you "this is the requirement".